# Why won't google adwords spend my entire budget

Tags: google-ads

I have a campaign on ad words. It's a "Test" area.. i give it $50 a day. One of the ad groups there was doing well with a 600% return. I moved it over to it's own campaign and gave it a budget of $500 a day.

The day is almost over and it yet to even spend $50. It should have cleared 400 by now if it's going to spend my 500.

Why is this happening? I am getting a good return why won't good spend all my money? Do they not want my money? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't have unlimited inventory.   Only a certain number of people actually perform the searches that you are bidding on every day.   Other people may also be bidding more than you and you ad is not showing up as often or as high as you would like. If you want more volume you can:

1. Bid on more keywords
2. Increase your bids

You indicate that you gave this keyword a "test".  If you ran a test for a short period of time, that test may not be a great indicator of future performance.   When you first put keywords into the system, Google doesn't have enough data to price them for you properly.  You may get more or less traffic during this time period than you will when you bid longer term.

There may also be a problem with your "quality score".  Google crawls your landing pages and tests showing your ads.  Based on these tests, it assigns your ad a score.  Much of this score is based on the click through rate (CTR) during these tests.  The better your quality score, the more you ad shows up even when you have low bids.

You say that you "moved it over to it's own campaign".  When you re-arrange your account, quality score may have to be re-computed.  If an ad is working in a specific campaign, it likely has a good quality score there and I would recommend that it not be moved.

Comment: I Have 10 key words I'm bidding on with 4 ads roating. One of the key words is a 10/10 quality score.  5 of them are 8 and 9.. the rest 7 and 6. I changed some things. Interesting thing is the one that is getting the most clicks is the 7/10 keyword then 10/10 isn't getting many at all. 10/10 doesn't even get as many impressions either.

I changed from "search network only" to "display and search network". I also upped my max cpc from .40 cents to 1 dollar. 

I will see what happens today, but any other guidance on what to do with such high quality keywords?

Comment: Still not spending all my money. Today it's 9:30 PST, it has only spent $27.20 out of my $200. I'm starting to think if i up my bid it will take all my money for sure, but then i'm not getting same ROI. I'm still not getting this.